# Is it possible to reinstall winodows with same key came with the machine

Tags: windows

I want to ask, if I format my computer (currently running windows10 genuine) and use some other OS for a while and then again install windows10, will I be able to reactivate my windows with the same key which is working currently on my pc ?

Comment: This question is off-topic for stackoverflow, as it's not related to programming. See [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) for general computing questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work just fine, provided you can install the same version. A key for Home won't work on Pro and vice versa, and there are also OEM versions and Volume License versions, so make sure which *exact* version you have.

If you have an installation CD or an ISO for the right edition (the one you have the key for) you'll be fine. You can re-install from that CD multiple times.

If Windows came preinstalled, you'd better make an image of the hard drive which you can restore later.